# How do I delete/update from nested document array

Tags: json, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

Given a document as below how can I delete or update from the nested document `ingredients` ? Any help, I am new to this rethinkdb. The table stores this documents called recipes.

```
[
    {
        "cook": "9 min",
        "id": "be63fc32-c1b5-4c67-a967-b6868f095216",
        "inactive": "20 min",
        "ingredients": [
            "2 cups fresh parsley leaves, chopped",
            "8 large sprigs fresh thyme, chopped",
            "4 large sprigs fresh rosemary, chopped",
            "3 cloves garlic, minced",
            "1 small shallot, diced",
            "2 tablespoons cracked black peppercorns",
            "2 tablespoons cracked pink peppercorns",
            "1 1/4 cups extra-virgin olive oil",
            "8 skin-on chicken thighs",
            "Flaky salt, such as Maldon, for seasoning",
            "Salad, for serving"
        ],
        "level": "Easy",
        "prep": "5 min",
        "title": "Asian Grilled Salmon",
        "total": "34 min",
        "yields": "6 servings"
    },
    ....
```

I tried as you see below, and it worked. But I want to know if there is a better way.

```
class Ingredients:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def update(self, recipe, name, position):
        __db__ = recipe.__class__.__db__()
        __table__ = recipe.__class__.__table__()
        result = (
            __table__.get(recipe.id)
            .update(
                {
                    "ingredients": __db__.r.row["ingredients"].change_at(
                        position, name
                    )
                }
            )
            .run(__db__.conn)
        )

        return recipe.ingredients

    @classmethod
    def destroy(self, recipe, recipe_name):
        __db__ = recipe.__class__.__db__()
        __table__ = recipe.__class__.__table__()
        __table__.get(recipe.id).update(
            {
                "ingredients": __db__.r.row["ingredients"].filter(
                    lambda name: name != recipe_name
                )
            }
        ).run(__db__.conn)

        return recipe.ingredients
```

`Ingredients` class is an attempt to model the `ingredients: [..]` part of the parent document in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **updating** you can iterate over the ingredients with `map`, find the one that you want to update and change its value:

```
r.db("test").table("sample").get("be63fc32-c1b5-4c67-a967-b6868f095216")
   .update({
     ingredients: r.row("ingredients").map(function(sub){  
       return r.branch(sub.eq("2 cups fresh parsley leaves, chopped"),
         "2 cups fresh baby poo, marinated", sub)
     })
   })
```

For **deleting** you can use the `difference` function:

```
r.db('test').table('sample').get('be63fc32-c1b5-4c67-a967-b6868f095216')
  .update({ingredients: r.row('ingredients')
    .difference(["4 large sprigs fresh rosemary, chopped"])});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will try them. What is `sub` doing here? Also what other active help sties are there where I can ask questions related to rethinkdb?

Comment: "sub" is just a variable, stands for one element in the array of ingredients. I don't know any active q&a sites for rethinkdb

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution after I posted this answer, so I added it to the main post. I think in case of destroy `difference` is much better than what I had tried. thanks for your time.

Comment: Ohh right, if you know the position then using the ´changeAt` is better ;) .